Perelman's proof applicability to wireframe sphere
From what I know, "In the proof of the Poincare Conjecture Perelman establishes the existence of an infinitely differentiable diffeomorphism between a homotopy 3-dimensional sphere and the ordinary 3-dimensional sphere."
My question is: can the homotopy 3-dimensional sphere be defined as wireframe model (in 3D modeling sense)? Or is the proof applicable to the continuous (infinitely differentiable) case only?

Please define what you mean by a "wireframe model". The space has to be a topological manifold, otherwise the theorem is simply false.

Topological manifold means "topological space" that locally resembles Euclidean space, in short. I assume the quote (from you, thanks) means "sphere in Euclidean space". One can define a sphere in Euclidean space using a set of interconnected triangles, for example - that will be a wireframe model of a sphere.

This does not really make sense, but, likely, you mean a triangulated 3-dimensional manifold. Then Perelman's theorem still applies (with a piecewise-linear homeomorphism instead of a diffeomorphism).

What exactly does not make sense in what I wrote - I'm genuinely curious. Can I trust Wikipedia? "In topology, a branch of mathematics, a topological manifold is a topological space that locally resembles real n-dimensional Euclidean space."

I mean the last sentence of your previous comment. I was asking you what does a "wireframe model mean" but instead of a definition (which should go to your post, not a comment) you wrote something else. But this something at least points in the right direction.

Thanks, I'm not proficient in topology's language then, because what you call a "sphere manifold" does really mean "sphere in a locally Euclidean space", on a practical level. Anyway, from your replies my suspicion that Perelman simply "zeroed-out" higher derivatives in his proof stands. It may be all nice and correct, but derivatives were eliminated.

First of all, it is hopeless to understand the result (I am not talking about the proof) without knowing at least some rudimentary topology (at least topological spaces, homeomorphisms, smooth atlas, diffeomorphisms, triangulations). Here is an answer to your question as I understand it.
There are three most common notions of manifolds in topology.

Topological manifolds. A (Hausdorff, 2nd countable) topological space $X$ is called an $n$-dimensional manifold if every point in $X$ has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. Two manifolds are regarded as "equivalent" in this setting if they are homeomorphic. This notion is the easiest one to understand but turns out to be the hardest to work with.

Differential manifolds. Suppose that $X$ is a Hausdorff, 2nd countable topological space. A smooth atlas on $X$ is a collection of open subsets $U_\alpha\subset X$ and homeomorphisms
$\phi_\alpha: U_\alpha\to \mathbb R^n$ such that all transition maps
$$
\phi_\alpha\circ \phi_\beta^{-1}
$$
are $C^\infty$-smooth (infinitely differentiable). A smooth manifold $M$ is a pair $(X,A)$, where  $A$ is a maximal smooth atlas on $X$. Then one defines smooth maps between smooth manifolds.
Two smooth manifolds are regarded as "equivalent" in this setting if they are diffeomorphic, i.e. there exists a $C^\infty$-smooth homeomorphism between the manifolds that has smooth inverse.

Piecewise-linear manifolds. There are two slightly different notions here, but in dimension 3 this distinction does not matter. First, one defines the notion of a simplicial complex, then the geometric realization of a simplicial complex. Then, notion of a triangulation of a topological space. A triangulation of a topological space $X$ is a pair $T=(C, f)$ consisting of a simplicial complex $C$ and a homeomorphism $f: |C|\to X$, where $|C|$ is the geometric realization of $C$. A triangulated manifold is a simplicial complex $C$ whose geometric realization is a topological manifold. Informally speaking, a 3-dimensional triangulated manifold is a collection of 3-dimensional tetrahedra and "gluing maps" between their faces, such that after identifying the faces using such maps (the technical notion you need to use here is "quotient topology", something you learn by taking a general topology class) results in a topological 3-dimensional manifold. Two triangulated manifolds $C_1, C_2$ are regarded as "equivalent" (piecewise-linearly isomorphic) if simplicial complexes $C_1, C_2$ admit subdivisions which are isomorphic as simplicial complexes. Note that I left many terms undefined terms here since giving all the necessary definitions will take too much space. But this is what, I think, you call a wireframe manifold. Note that this definition is the most complex of all three. However, for many purposes, it is the easiest one to work with and, traditionally, most low-dimensional topology (dimensions 2 and 3) is done by working with piecewise-linear manifolds.


In dimensions $\ge 4$ these three notions lead to different (but related) theories of manifolds. However, in dimensions $\le 3$, as it turns out, all three notions are equivalent. For instance, every topological 3-dimensional manifold admits a smooth atlas and also can be triangulated. Also, every two homeomorphic triangulated 3-dimensional manifolds are piecewise-linearly isomorphic, etc. This was known for about 40 years before Perelman's work.
Now, after we are done with all the preliminaries (skipping most!), here is the actual answer to your question:
Suppose that $M$ is a 3-dimensional triangulated manifold homotopy-equivalent to the 3-dimensional sphere $S^3$. Then it is piecewise-linearly isomorphic to $S^3$ with 'standard" triangulation (the boundary of the 4-dimensional simplex). How does one prove this? First of all, the topological space $X$ underlying $M$ admits a smooth structure $A$. Next, by Perelman's theorem, the smooth manifold $(X,A)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^3$ (with the standard smooth structure). Lastly, one promotes this diffeomorphism to a piecewise-linear homeomorphism of triangulated manifolds. The 1st and the last step use the "equivalence" of three notions of manifolds in dimension 3 that I mentioned above.

Thank you, it may take some time for my brain to swallow information, but usually in several months I understand things better. Also thanks for using "equivalent" term instead of homeomorphic, because for an untrained mind these are the same thing. I know science loves to invent language, but it does not always work for starters.

Then my main suspicion about Perelman's proof is that "wireframe manifold" (non-differentiable) cannot not be equivalent to "sphere manifold" (infinitely differentiable). Equivalence may be on the level of A=B, but the proof may miss "filtering effects" of smoothing operation (as you've told in our prior discussion). Topological smoothing is the same thing as averaging in statistics - it eliminates derivatives and non-differentiability.

I'm not an expert in topology, but I hope you can make something out of this observation of mine. I'm not going to publish any paper on that. Thanks I've found you.

Then consider two independent "wireframe manifolds" derived from sphere via triangulation with differing parameters - one contains 1000 vertices and the other contains 2000 vertices. They have a differing profile of their surfaces. It's just hardly possible to define homotopy for them -  the number of vertices is discrete.

If you really want to understand how these things work, you have to learn topology systematically. @aleksv

It does not look reliable to learn it seriously. $1000000 prize won't help it.

@aleksv: Then think of some other subjects.
